Switch ruby version on Mac M1
I would like to switch Ruby versions on my Mac M1. My understanding is that Mac comes with a preinstalled version of Ruby (in my case, when I run ruby -v I get:
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin23]
I have installed ruby with brew:
ruby 3.3.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
How can I switch to this version? Nothing I have found online and tried has helped me so far.
I feel like something in one of my configuration files may be causing a conflict somewhere that doesn't allow me to switch versions.
Here is my .zshrc:
if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=⁠ gem environment gemdir ⁠/bin:$PATH
fi

#export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"

#[ -f "/Users/xxx/.ghcup/env" ] && source "/Users/xxx/.ghcup/env" # ghcup-env
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin"


export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi

unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

[ -f "/Users/xxx/.ghcup/env" ] && source "/Users/xxx/.ghcup/env" # ghcup-env

if [ "$ARCH" = '' ]
then
  ARCH=⁠ arch ⁠
fi
export TOOLDIR=$HOME/c-tools
export PATH="$TOOLDIR/bin:$TOOLDIR/bin/$ARCH:$PATH"
if [ "$MANPATH" = '' ]
then
  export MANPATH=$TOOLDIR/man
else
  export MANPATH=${MANPATH}:$TOOLDIR/man
fi

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/xxx/flutter/flutter-2/bin"

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/xxx/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/xxx/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/xxx/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/xxx/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'; fi

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/bin/java)

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

Here is my .bash_profile:
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

. "$HOME/.cargo/env"

# >>> coursier install directory >>>
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin"
# <<< coursier install directory <<<

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/xxx/prolog/bin/sicstus-4.7.0

Here is my .profile:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

# >>> coursier install directory >>>
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin"
# <<< coursier install directory <<<

I understand that most of the above is irrelevant but I have given these as I feel like there may be a conflict somewhere that is causing my issue.

You don't really want to do this. Instead use a ruby version manager like rvm, asdf, rbenv, etc.

All three of these fail at the build stage. I think the problem is to do with openssl and psych not being configured, but they are both already installed on my machine.

OK I managed to get it working with rvm by running rvm install 3.3.1 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1. Thank you so much!

Personally, I use ruby-install to download my ruby versions and chruby for switching. Other popular version managers are RVM and RBenv, which both have functions for installing and switching rubies all-in-one. I prefer the lightweightness of chruby and ruby-install though.
For ruby-install/chruby, it'd look something like this:
# first install via homebrew
brew install ruby-install 
brew install chruby 

After installing chruby, you want to add a couple lines to your .zshrc file:
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh

Then in command line, just do:
# download ruby 
ruby-install ruby-3.3.1 # or whichever version

# Switch ruby version
chruby ruby-3.3.1


But when I add the lines to .zshrc, I get:
/Users/xxx/.zshrc:source:78: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh

Why would this be happening?

Probably depends on your local env and version of chruby. Those are the references I am using, but might be different for you. I would follow the chruby installation directions on their github.
Also, I believe the post-install directions for chruby, will tell you the exact references you need in your .zshrc
